# searching on multiple values in php

Tags: php, mysql, search, select, resultset

I have a form in which there are three text fields and user enter email in any or all of them, I need to check if that email is present in db or not.
The problem is that may be the user fills only 1 field, may be I get more than one result from DB, the query I wrote in php is

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_email WHERE (emailAddr = '{$d1]}' OR emailAddr = '{$d2}' OR emailAddr = '{$d3}') AND email!='' LIMIT 1";
```

Thinking about different use cases in which may be there is empty field, nothing is written, Am i doing right?

Comment: LIMIT 1 will make sure you get maximum of 1 row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ignore exactly how you are using the syntax with the brackets, but it could be something like this:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM 
  user_email 
WHERE 
  email 
IN 
  ('$d1','$d2','$d3') 
LIMIT 
  1
```

That is to say, if there is an email that equals one of this three, return the row.

Comment: what if the user fills nothing and there a blank row in user_email table that shouldn't be returned

Comment: @user1765876 then validate email with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` before running the query!

Comment: or add " and email is not null and email !=' ' "

Comment: @user1765876 or using SQL query, I think something like this, e.g.: `SELECT * FROM user_email WHERE email LIKE '%_@__%.__% AND IN ('$d1','$d2','$d3')` (not tested but should work)